# Android studio and gradle internet

Tags: android-studio, gradle, apk

Is it compulsory that Android studio must be connected to the internet to use gradle for debugging an android project and creating an apk file

Answer (score 0):

You can run in offline mode. But any update to build.gradle will need internet connection to sync the project